# Picturefill.js: Need help converting <picture> to the <img> srcset/sizes method

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, picturefill

This is what I have...

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="assets/images/home/desktop-hero.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)" />
    <source srcset="assets/images/home/mobile-hero.jpg" media="(max-width: 767px)" />
    <img class="hero-image-main ratio-content" src="assets/images/home/mobile-hero.jpg" />
</picture>
```

Comment: Why was this downed? The title clearly states what I need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the "mobile" image is a scaled-down version of the "desktop" image, and the widths of the images are 384 and 768 respectively, and you want the image to be 100vw wide up to 768px...

```
<img src="assets/images/home/mobile-hero.jpg"
     srcset="assets/images/home/mobile-hero.jpg 384w,
             assets/images/home/desktop-hero.jpg 768w"
     sizes="(min-width:768px) 768px, 100vw">
```

If your "mobile" image is a cropped version of the "desktop" image (art direction), then you should be using `<picture>`. (You can drop the second `<source>` though, the `<img>` is picked up as a candidate.)